# Double pipe to save output to file in C

Tags: c

I have created something like "linux pipe" to redirect  output from one program to another and it's working like a charm. But now I want to save final output to a file. On the internet I saw that I need to create double pipe, but everything I create is not working.

Here is my actual code of "pipe":

```
 int pipes[2];
 int pid;
 pipe(pipes);
 if(pid=fork()){
         int fd = open("t.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   close(pipes[1]);
   dup2(pipes[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    execvp(sec_command[0],sec_command);

 }
     else{

   close(pipes[0]);
   dup2(pipes[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
   execvp(first_command[0],first_command);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need an extra pipe to save the output to a file.  You need to open the file you want and have the code write to that.

Comment: please, post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can test it. And please, also indent appropiately the code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You don't need to.  You just need to do a second `dup2` in the child process (which will be capturing its input from the pipe) to the file descriptor of the file you want the output to go.  You haven't post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and your code is wrong (it `exec`s in the parent and child process) so i've tried to work a complete solution.  Here it is:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t
subcommand_to_file(
        char **subcommand_args,
        char *file)
{
    int pipes[2];
    pipe(pipes);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        int fd = open(file,
                O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR,
                0666); /* permissions controled by umask */
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(pipes[1]); /* close output descriptor of pipe */
        dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO); /* redirect input */
        close(pipes[0]); /* not needed after dup2 */
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); /* rediect output */
        close(fd); /* not needed after dup2 */
        execvp(subcommand_args[0], subcommand_args);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* parent */
    close(pipes[0]); /* close input descriptor of pipe */
    dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipes[1]); /* not needed, after dup */
    return pid; /* so if you want to wait for the child */
}

int
main(   int argc,
        char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    char file[256];

    /* default value for filename */
    snprintf(file, sizeof file, "%s.out", argv[0]);

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'f':
            strncpy(file, optarg, sizeof file);
            break;
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    pid_t child = subcommand_to_file(argv, file);
    if (child < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "subcommand_to_file: %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* copy input to output to pass stdin to  subprocess */
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    wait(NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s terminated\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The above program is called as

```
$ a.out -f output_file  command [args ...]
```

and will end when the `command` program is finished.  Just try

```
$ a.out -f out.txt echo a b c
```

and you will get

```
$ cat out.txt
a b c
$ _
```